# jQuery new Object .bind

Tags: jquery

I've come across a code snippet that i am trying to understand. I did not find it anywhere. The code still works fine. Its about the .bind function of jQuery:

```
$(new Object()).bind()
```

what does the bind function of jQuery do with " new Object() ". Can someone elaborate?! Thanks.

Comment: you told that it works, what exactly this code does at your codebase? In what purpose you used it?

Comment: its quite a bit of code ... im just looking over it.. and saw this - looked up in the internet - didn find it - and thought asking the community if somebody knows that kind of thing. Here the function:  $(new Object()).bind("something", function(event, data){ });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it solved. For someone who is interested-> There are two parts to it:

```
<a id="refButton" href="#">Click Me !!</a>

**Part 1:**   


    $(new Object()).bind("pressMe", function(event, data){
             $(document).ready(function(){
                   $('#refButton').bind("click",function(){
                      alert("Hi There !!");
                    });
             });
        });


**Part 2**

    if(some condition == TRUE){
      $.event.trigger("pressMe");
    }
```

So, everybody knows that *"$(document).ready(function(){"* gets executed first - but - in this way only when Part2 condition is TRUE than it triggers the "pressMe" event defined in Part1 which ultimately listens to the click event of the #refButton Id.

But it still remains a mistery to me how the empty new Object() - disables the *"$(document).ready(function(){"* functionality till the trigger is activated.

But thanks to all who answered.

Comment: It "disables" it because the `$(document).ready()` code is *inside* the handler function, and the handler will not run until the event happens. If you put `alert("Hello World")` inside the handler, then that also would not run until the event was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

That statement by itself won't do anything, really, except possibly result in a runtime error. The jQuery "bind()" method requires at least one parameter.

Even with a parameter, it won't do anything, however, because it's all about event handler binding. It doesn't make sense to do that to a plain JavaScript object.

The "bind()" call is normally used like this (though there are variations):

```
$('selector').bind('event-name', function(ev) { /* event handler code */ });
```

The "selector" string is used to find one or more DOM elements in a page.

Comment: Its more like this:                                                                    $(new Object()).bind("something", function(event, data){
     
    });

Comment: Well why did you not put that in the original question?  Had it not occurred to you that function arguments might be important when determining what a function does?

Comment: Well sorry -  but new Object() - what kind of a selector does it reference to - or any

Comment: That's what I meant by my answer - `new Object()` just creates a plain JavaScript object, and it really doesn't make sense to bind an event handler to it. I don't think it'll hurt anything, however, which is probably why the code appears to "work".

Comment: yeah i know it has to be a specific selector but "new Object()" does not make any sense - as far as i understand - but astonishing that it does not give any errors - but thnks

Comment: Well jQuery is OK with the idea of wrapping any aribitrary object in a jQuery wrapper; for example, `$(new Date())` is weird but not treated as an error. There are a few useful things to be done with that, like using ".each()" or ".map()" or ".filter()".

Comment: hmm ... $(new Object()).bind("something", function(event, data){ });
 <-- can this mean that any ".event" that fires the "something" event gets executed what there is in the function ???!!!!!  .... its being used like this afterwards -> $.event.trigger("something", [jsonObject]);

Comment: Well it certainly won't handle events that occur on any DOM element - it may be that it's possible to get jQuery to dispatch the events when they're explicitly triggered, however. I don't know what the point of doing that would be, however, since if you're going to write code to explicitly trigger the event via some known jQuery object, you could just as well simply call a function ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(new Object()).bind("something", function(event, data){ });
```

This means that you are binding a function delegate with parameters "event" and "data" to new object's "something" event. Whenever the newly created object fires "something" event, the function will execute.

Comment: You said "Whenever the newly created object fires "something" event," ---> does this mean any newly created Object?

Comment: no, just the one instantiated in the declaration. To bind it to any you need another approach of selecting the object. Try adding class to those objects and using $(".NewObjectClass").bind() instead

Comment: :-) thanks for the answer but this is the initial question - i know it has to be a specific selector but new Object() what kind of a selector is that to bind something to

Comment: as Pointy explained it just creates a blank instance of an object in memory, without a type. So i guess wherever you got that example from, they used it as a placeholder to show that .bind() method requires an instance of an object. just new object() won't do anything.

Comment: hmm its a finished company product that my einstein brain is trying to understand....

Comment: can you provide the full code? is the bind() followed with another dot command? or is the $(new object()) assigned to a variable? Just the part of your posted code won't do anything since it creates a generic javascript object with no properties and assigns an event handler. but since the object is generic, it won't have any events to fire. so the code won't do anything as it is in your question